# Open an cobol index-sequential file with the file name in a variable

Tags: cobol

I use Microfocus Net Express 5.1 (Cobol).

When I want to open an index-sequential file I write

```
open input xyzfile
```

My question is: Is there somehow a possibility to put the name "xyzfile" in variable an write instead

```
move "xyzfile" to var-file
open input var-file
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: `var-file` isn't a file name. In your `file control` section you can assign the file to a variable name: `SELECT var-file ASSIGN TO input-file-name` ... where `input-file-name` is defined in your `working storage` section.

Comment: I'm sure this is covered in your documentation. As @lurker has indicated, it is the SELECT statement you need to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from environment division;

```
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select ConfigFile
              assign to wFile-folder
              organization is line sequential
              file status is wStatus.
```

from working-storage section;

```
   working-storage section.
   01  wFile-folder                pic x(256).
   01  wStatus                     pic x(2).
```

and under your procedure division;

```
      move "c:\data\configuration.txt" to wFile-folder
      open input ConfigFile

      read ConfigFile record
```